# Can I get in to Peru if my US passport is vaild for 4 months only?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, peru

I'm planning to travel from the US to Peru next week but just found out my passport expires in mid June. Is this a problem? My flight back is already booked for 10 days after

Answer (score 2):

According to the [US State Department page for Peru](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Peru.html):

> **PASSPORT VALIDITY:**
>
> Must have six months validity at time of entry.

International travel is already complicated enough right now, I would suggest that you [get new passport as soon as possible](https://www.usa.gov/passport#item-34927).

Comment: According to that link you referenced, the [passport processing times](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/how-apply/processing-times.html) for normal expedited/non-urgent travel are 5-7 weeks.  But it looks they have super expedited process if you can make an appointment, when you have travel within 3 business days.  The [How to get a passport quickly](https://www.usa.gov/passport#item-34927) does suggest you can get it sooner if you can convince them that it is urgent travel